# trying to deploy hardhat scripts, npm ERR! code E404

Tags: node.js, npm, error-handling, solidity, hardhat

Trying to run my `deploy.js` scripts with hardhat but this error keeps popping up.

```
npx hardhart run scripts/deploy.js
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hardhart - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'hardhart@latest' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kalar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-10T19_36_11_300Z-debug-0.log
```

I've checked other solutions to this issue and have tried

- updating registry
- npm force update
- npm cache clean
- re-installing dependencies
- deleting .npmrc file

none of the above are working, not sure what else to try

Answer (score 0):

Figure this has already been resolved. Looks like you needed to run

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js
```

npx hard**hart**